# How to implement this asynchronous Parse Login as a CallBack function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, parse-platform, callback

This is a question related on how to use callbacks in Swift for Asynchronous functions. I am not able to understand how callbacks exactly workk.

I want to call `logIn()` when a button is pressed and then keep the UI active (i.e. not block the main thread while `logInWithUsernameInBackground` is waiting for response).

My question is how can I put this function in another class (i.e. not in my viewcontroller) and then get a `Bool` whether login was successful or not?

**I just want to know how to split up this function, when the calling part is in my ViewController but I can have another `onLoginComplete` that I can place in some other class.

```
func logIn() {

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(tv_username.text, password:tv_password.text) {
            (user, error) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                if user != nil {
                    // Yes, User Exists

                    self.goToMainMenu()

                } else {
                    // No, User Doesn't Exist
                    println("logIn() - User Doesn't Exist")
                }
            } else {
                //if error show popup                    
                self.showUIAlertPopup("Oops, something went wrong", msg: "Either user exists or you are not connected", btn_text: "Try again")
            }

        }
    }
```

**what I am actually trying to do is place the Asynchronous network call in a totally different class. So my question is - how do I update the ViewController once the network operation is complete if the network operation is done in a different class separate than the ViewController?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a completion handler like I did here.

```
class func getGroupFromNameWithBlock(name: String, completion: (result: Bool) -> Void){
    self.query().whereKey("name", equalTo: name).getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (object, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            completion(result: true)
        } else {
            completion(result: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what I am actually trying to do is place the Asynchronous network call in a totally different class. So my question is - how do I update the ViewController once the network operation is complete if the network operation is done in a different class separate than the ViewController? Sorry if it was not clear, I will add this to the question.

Comment: That's what I did, this is a class function so you can put it anywhere.

Comment: If you don't want completion handler you can use a delegate method which could be called when the user is logged. Or post an NSNotification but delegate are more clean. But it's not so much different than updating your viewController depending on the completion handler Boolean result.